# How to: replace command

Tags: javascript, replace

can any one tell me how i can keep commas"," and dots"." along with the numbers? 
have tried some searching on google but i didn't find any thing that i could understand.

```
 string2 = string2.replace(/\D./g,'');


      var element1 = document.getElementById("content"),
        style1 = window.getComputedStyle(element1),
        height1 = style1.getPropertyValue('height');
        var string1 = height1;
        string1 = string1.replace(/\D/g,'');
        alert(string1);


      var element2 = document.getElementById("nav-menu"),
        style2 = window.getComputedStyle(element2),
        height2 = style2.getPropertyValue('height');
        var string2 = height2;
        string2 = string2.replace(/\D./g,'');
        alert(string2);


        var x = string1/string2;
        var z = 100/x
```

Comment: `string2 = string2.replace(/[^\d\.]/g,"");`

I just had to add a `\.` after the `\D`

figured i don't need the , any way since it use 31.31 not 31,31

Comment: Kevin, if your problem is solved (as it sounds), please select one of the answers (or create a new one of your own and select that). In this way, others can see what really works and what doesn't. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

string2 = string2.replace(/[^\d.]/g,""); I just had to add a . after the \D figured i don't need the , any way since it use 31.31 not 31,31

Answer (score 0):

I really have no idea what you want to achieve, but the dot is a special character in regexes, matching any single character. So `string2.replace(/\D./g,'')` will not "keep commas and dots", because the regex matches a \D plus the next char (whatever it is). If you want to match only a dot, it must be escaped or put into a character class.

Comment: I am new to string.replace and i have no idea <br> 
would something like this work then .replace(0-9+.+, , '')

Comment: If you want to play around with regexes (the stuff between the /s), visit debuggex.com: You can enter a regex and see a graphical representation of accepted strings, and you can enter sample strings and see which parts are matching the regex. Really nice!

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right - you are trying to extract property values from styles strings. I would do it this way:

```
var regex = /([\d\.\,]+)(\s)?[a-z\%]+/gi;
alert(regex.test("height: 38.5%;")[1]); // will show 38.5
```

alternatively

```
alert(regex.test("height: 38.5%;")[0]); // will show 38.5%, as the whole matched expression
```

**UPDATE:**
consider using jQuery http://jquery.com/

Comment: I am not allowed to use JQuery
and im not sure how to put that code inn?

Comment: `string2 = string2.replace(/[^\d\.]/g,"");`

I just had to add a `\.` after the `\D`

figured i don't need the , any way since it use 31.31 not 31,31